# Difference between File.listFiles and Files.newDirectoryStream

Tags: java, swing, filestream

I'm working on a MutableTree that shows system directory structure.

For the root item FileSystemView.getRoots() is used which returns Desktop directory as root directory which is fine.

When desktopRoot.listFiles() is invoked I get "My Computer", " Documents", etc.. Together with Desktop files and folders created by user.

However, when newDirectoryStream(desktopRoot) is invoked only the user created files and folders are returned without "My Computer", " Documents", etc..

File.listFiles() is slow for large directories so my question is: can "My Computer", " Documents", be listed using newDirectoryStream(desktopRoot) or should I add this entries manually as first level tree entries?

Comment: I'd hate to think of the state of a Desktop where this optimisation is relevant.

Comment: Its not about desktop, its whole system tree which is loaded 1 level in advance to show + handles before the non empty folders. So if you go Desktop -> My Computer -> C -> Windows - it takes a second or two to fill windows directories which is annoying